# Fast 2-dimensional array (matrix) in Python without C extensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, python-2.x

I need to write a plugin for an application which is extensible using Python 2.7. It needs to execute a rather complex dynamic algorithm which works on a rectangular matrix of integers.

The default Python installation that comes with that application does not include a numeric library like `numpy`, so unfortunately I have to implement this using only the Python `stdlib`.

I've tried several different approaches to represent the matrix in memory:

```
values = defaultdict(int)
values = [[0 for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
values = [0] * (width * height)   # access like values[j*width + i] later
values = [[0] * width for _ in range(height)]
```

The dict approach is only there for completeness, it's actually not good performing because every element is accessed.

From my measurements, the last of these seems the fastest to build and access. However, I am surprised that there is no built-in matrix functionality. From what I have learned about Python so far, if you don't find some obvious functionality in the `stdlib`, the most likely reason is that you haven't looked hard enough.

So I wonder whether this can be optimized even further. For example using the `array` module or some other feature that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is the chocie of data structure?

Comment: @Sven: Yes, the algorithm basically only compares and modifies values in the matrix accordingly. Switching a from a tuple-indexed dict to a list of lists gave me about 50% more performance. Profiling (using `kernprof`) shows that most of the time is needed using getting and setting values from the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `array` module might be faster when the matrix gets large, because it can pack values more compactly; it can be used with the `values[j*width + i]` convention. But no, there's no multidimensional array in the Python standard library, probably because (a) Numpy already fills that niche effectively and (b) you can always make a list of lists if performance is not paramount.

The fastest option really depends on the algorithm. The `dict`-based approach might actually be the fastest when the matrices you're handling are very sparse (which in DP algorithms they're usually not, at least not in the ones I saw).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually `array` seems to be even a bit slower in that case then a simple `[0]*(width*height)`, so that's not an option either. I guess it's gotta be slow, then :) Maybe I'm going to make it optional to use numpy, so users have the choice. I guess that could be a good solution.

Comment: I found that `array` is usually slower than using a list -- here are some [simple example timimngs](https://gist.github.com/1935721).  I wouldn't even expect it to be faster -- it just uses less memory.

Comment: @Sven: Yeah, that's what I figured as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a default dictionary, and use 2-tuples as indexes, or implement a custom class and implement the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to deal with 2-tuples as indexes and store the result in a Python array:

```
from array import array
class Array2D(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.data = array("f", [0] * w * h)
        self.width = w
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index[1] * self.width + index[0]]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
          self.data[index[1] * self.width + index[0]] = value
```

Or, using a defaultdict, you might get better performance:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
>>> d[0,0]
0
>>> d[0,0] = 2.5
>>> d[0,0]
2.5
>>>
```

Comment: Both of these approaches are included in my question, with the comment that a simple `[[0] * width for _ in range(height)]` is actually faster. I also mentioned the fact that every item is actually accessed, so the space advantage of the dictionary solution is also annihilated.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
arr=[*map(lambda a: [a]*cols,[0]*rows)]
```

this will create a 2D (rows x cols) matrix of zeros

> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]